# Pass array of floats when training Stanford CRFClassifier

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

For every word in a document, I'm looking to add in a series of floating point numbers as features for Stanford NER's `CRFClassifier` to train on.  Unfortunately, the documentation on Stanford NER's `.prop` files hasn't made it clear how to pass in custom features. In general, how does one go about adding custom features to a Stanford NER training set?

Comment: Do you know how (using which file/function) to re-train the Stanford NER?

Comment: Yes, the stanford ner docs are fairly clear on the basics: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#b

Comment: Have you looked inside the class NERFeatureFactory ?

Comment: Ah, thanks! That's where that info is located. If you link to that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find your answer inside the 'NERFeatureFactory' class.